# adding two numbers in a textbox

Tags: android

In the following section of the code i try to add two numbers in a textbox,when i add two small numbers it works fine but when two large numbers for instance if i add 552886588 and 5588488 i get 5.58475076E8

```
 if (check.isChecked()) {
                TextView tv1_chq = (TextView)    popupView.findViewById(R.id.subname3);
                TextView tv2_chq = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.subtotal3);
                tv1_chq.setText("CHEQUE AMOUNT:");


                Double sum_cheque = Double.parseDouble(totalamt_checknew.getText().toString());

                    if (rootlayout_check.getChildCount() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= rootlayout_check.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
                            View v;
                            v = rootlayout_check.getChildAt(i);
                            EditText et3 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.checktotal);
                            sum_cheque = sum_cheque + Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
                        }

            }
                tv2_chq.setText(String.valueOf(sum_cheque));
```

Comment: The result is correct. Is it not?

Comment: yes it is but i want it in integer format

Comment: `i want it in integer format ` - then why you use `Double`s, and not `Integer`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f you add two double numbers or at least one of them is double, you can use

`String.format("%.0f", sum_cheque);`

If your aim is to add two large integer numbers that won't work.

In this case you can use `long` instead of `double`.

```
long d1 = Long.parseLong(etext1.getText().toString());
long d2 = Long.parseLong(etext2.getText().toString());
long ans = d1 + d2;
textView.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
```

**Edit 1:**
If you want to add decimal numbers and integer numbers, you can use `BigDecimal`

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(etext1.getText().toString());
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(etext2.getText().toString());

BigDecimal d = d1.add(d2);

d.intValue();
textView.setText(d.toString());
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Please see if it is what you want and if not please explain what you want clearly.

Comment: its not working ,it still comes in hexadecimal format